# I am installing Microsoft Biztalk Adapter Pack on Windows 64bit

Tags: oracle11g, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have already installed Oracle 11g Client and WCF LOB Adapter successfully. However I
am getting following error:

> There is Problem with this windows installer package. A program
>   required for this  install to complete could not be run.Contact you
>   support personnel or package vendor.

Can any body please suggest me how can I fix it?

Comment: "Contact your support personnel or package vendor." seems fairly specific.

Comment: I have downloaded it from microsoft site properly.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2755

Answer (score 0):

Try following [these steps](http://biztalkin-howard.blogspot.com/2011/11/biztalk-2010-wcf-lob-oracle-adapter.html). Getting the WCF adapters setup with BizTalk can be somewhat touchy. Also, make sure you do not have an older version of the oracle client installed.